# Magento points to wrong paths in duplicated project

Tags: magento-1.8

I created a duplicate of my project including the database.

I changed the value in the magento database table `core_config_data` where path is **`web/unsecure/base_url`** and **`web/secure/base_url`** to
 **http://localhost/projects/botec/devLocal/**

But images are still pointing to a false path e.g.

`http://localhost/media/wysiwyg/kategorie_bilder/example.jpg`

instead of

`http://localhost/projects/botec/devLocal/media/wysiwyg/kategorie_bilder/example.jpg`

[image]

**I already cleared the cache in "var/cache"**

Comment: Seems that you have used **`/media/wysiwyg/kategorie_bilder/example.jpg`** in CMS content instead of **`{{media url=''wysiwyg/kategorie_bilder/example.jpg}}`**. Please check and confirm.

Comment: Yes unfortunately this is true, do I have to change every single occurence now or is there a trick?

Comment: You can export data of **cms_block** and **cms_page** tables, open it in any text editor and try to find and replace URL paths with proper paths.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you have used **`/media/wysiwyg/kategorie_bilder/example.jpg`** in CMS content instead of **`{{media url=''wysiwyg/kategorie_bilder/example.jpg}}`**.

In order to fix that, you need to:

1. Export the data from **cms_page** and **cms_block** tables.
2. Keep the copy of exported data, so that you can import it back if any problem occurs.
3. Open exported data in a text editor and try to find and replace the URL paths using same path occurrences.
4. Truncate both tables.
5. Import the changed data back to the database.
6. Flush Magento's cache and check again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a virtual host, now Magento sees the project root as root.